# how to use transaction within Zend_Db_Table?

Tags: zend-framework, transactions

because of historical reason, all of the models extend from Zend_Db_Table. and now ,I need to use transaction. how?

I did some googling, some peaple say the following way can help:

1: $tableA->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();
2: $tableA->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

is there any better solution?

Comment: Which database adapter are you using? [Here it the link you need](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.transactions)

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem by adding the following code into zend_db_table:
/**
     * surport transaction
     */

```
public function beginTransaction() {
    $this->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();
}
public function commit() {
    $this->getAdapter()->commit();
}
public function rollback() {
    $this->getAdapter()->rollback();
}
```

so that I can use transaction in models that extend from zend_db_table like this:

```
public function test(){
    $this->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $this->addCourseItem('1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
        $this->fetchRow("none-exist-field = 1");
        //the following code will not execute
        echo "okay";
        $this->commit();
    } catch (exception $e) {
        $this->rollback();
        echo "error message:".$e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are saying that you altered the framework code, I'm going to say bad developer.

Comment: @RockyFord I agree, but OTOH adding an abstract class that inherits Zend_Db_Table, implements that code, and gets inherited by all his models would be perfectly kosher.